# Correctly handling a Reload and Restart from the AppletViewer

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, applet, awt

When my applet starts up the first time from a clean environment, things work the way I expect them to. I spawn two threads, one for generic processing, and one for graphics. I do all GUI manipulation calls from the event dispatching thread. Start/Stop is handled correctly from the appletviewer, but Restart/Reload is not. I have a Canvas called `drawCanvas` as the only Component in my Applet's content pane, and I use double buffering to draw to it.

I observe the problem here:

```
public void start() {   
    /* ... some stuff  */
    executeOnEDTAndWait( 
        new Thread() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                /* ... more stuff ... */
                setupDrawCanvas();

                if( drawCanvas.isDisplayable() ) {
                    drawCanvas.createBufferStrategy(2); 
                    /* ... some more stuff */
                } else {
                    /* This is where it runs into difficulties */
                }
    /* ... */
```

Where `setupDrawCanvas` is defined like this:

```
private void setupDrawCanvas() {
    setVisible(false);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    getContentPane().removeAll();

    drawCanvas = new Canvas();

    drawCanvas.setName("drawCanvas");
    drawCanvas.setSize(
    newDrawCanvasDimension.width, 
    newDrawCanvasDimension.height);
    drawCanvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

    getContentPane().add(drawCanvas);

    getContentPane().setVisible(true);
    drawCanvas.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, here's the relevant code in `destroy()`

```
public void destroy() {
    /* .. some stuff .. */

    /* dispose of drawCanvas */
    drawCanvas.setVisible(false);
    if( drawCanvas.getBufferStrategy() != null ) {
        drawCanvas.getBufferStrategy().dispose();
    }

    /* reset and disable the applet's GUI */
    setVisible(false);
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    removeAll();

    /* .. some more stuff */
```

The first time through, everything works fine. When I do a restart from the `appletviewer`, first `stop()` is called which causes all my threads to enter into wait states. Then `destroy()` is called which wakes all my threads up again and lets them exit, as well as do and `invokeAndWait()` on the EDT to clean up my widgets and do a setVisible(false). So after destroy completes the `appletviewer` calls init/start again and the process repeats exactly as before, except it fails in `start()` at the region I noted above.

Something that I noticed which made very little sense to me was that if I cloned the applet using the `appletviewer` and then reloaded the clone, everything would work as expected when I attempted to restart or reload the clone the first time, but would crash with an exception the second time.

Something else I noticed while trying to debug this problem is that the `appletviewer` and a browser act *completely* differently as hosts to my applet; they don't even call `init()` and `start()` under the same conditions. Also, restart and reload seem to be nothing more than a call to `stop()` -> `destroy()` -> `init()` -> `start()` but with subtle modifications to the execution environment.

So my question is, what is the significance of the restart and reload operations (i.e. when are they used) and is it a problem that my applet fails in the appletviewer when they occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice Question.
To answer this question we need understand the blocks of java code first.
we have a anonymous, static blocks before construtor that will be executed.

```
package com.test;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class AppletTest extends Applet {
    {
        System.out.println("I m Anonymous block");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("I m static block");
    }

    public AppletTest()
    {
        System.out.println("I m constructor");
    }

    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("start");
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("stop");   
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        System.out.println("destory");   
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("test Applet",10,10);
    }
}
```

invocation:

```
 <applet code="AppletTest.class" height=300 width=300></applet>
```

when running this class using appletviewer you can note the difference. 
Applet running for the first time you will get

```
    I m static block
    I m Anonymous block
    I m constructor
    init
    start
```

while doing applet restart -

```
stop
destory
init
start
```

and on applet reload

```
stop
destory
I m Anonymous block
I m constructor
init
start
```

for your second question, applet does not guarantee the same output on different OS, network and hardware components.